# Android Text View display html tags as a text

Tags: android

**Text View**
when i try to get text from web and display it in text view it generates html tags

like

Boy: how are you 
Girl:&nbps; fine

is there any way to remove these text from the text view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jokeText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#DC143C"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text=""/>


</LinearLayout>
```

i need help pls solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

jokeText.setText(Html.fromHtml("&nbps; fine"));

Comment: Yep. I was also gonna write the same answer.

Comment: Thanks  brother in text view there is a variable set which i get from the web. i want my text free of html tag

Comment: public String removeHtml(String html) {
    return Html.fromHtml(your_html_text).toString();
}

Comment: some time times text come from web there is space in text the text view auto generates &nbps; if there is text has new line the text view generates <bar> tag as text format is there any solution.